# how to show notification to notification tray when app is in foreground

Tags: android, notifications

I have problem about notification using firebase.. 
How to show notification in notification tray when app is in foreground? I have tried the notification can appear only when app is in background

this my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private TextView txtRegId, txtMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtRegId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reg_id);
        txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // checking for type intent filter
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                    // gcm successfully registered
                    // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                    displayFirebaseRegId();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                    // new push notification is received

                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    txtMessage.setText(message);
                }
            }
        };

        displayFirebaseRegId();
    }



    // Fetches reg id from shared preferences
    // and displays on the screen
    private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

        Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
            txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
        else
            txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // register GCM registration complete receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

        // register new push message receiver
        // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

        // clear the notification area when the app is opened
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
}
```

Notification Utils

```
public class NotificationUtils {

    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;


        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);

        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                } else {
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                }
            }
        } else {
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to use getData instead of GetNotification

Comment: where I can place that code?

Comment: you have to change in both side. in Andorid: use remoteMessage.getData()  instead of remoteMessage.getNotification().   and in server side you have to send Data payload instead of Notification

Comment: I already send data payload instead of Notification in server side.. and in android side when I use remoteMessage.getData() there be error.. `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on a null object reference`

Comment: use it:  @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
       
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

Comment: I'm not really understand.. here's my code now after use yout suggestion.. https://pastebin.com/zRTwJxtQ sorry using external link

Comment: change to this handleNotification(data);   and for getting field like TITLE use data.get("title");

Comment: I have try, and notification still can't appear in notification tray

Comment: did you check with LOG. inside of onMessageReceived if it is called.

Comment: yes, I have LOG inside of onMessageReceived, and the LOG show message

Comment: then your notifictaion code has problem. did yu change all field with data.get("key") to show notification?

Comment: yes, I already using data.get("key")

Comment: check your notification builder code and check logcat also, maybe there is some error/warning

Comment: can you please post the logs that prints when app is in foreground state? as post the message that you are sending from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change all `isInBackground = false;` in class NotificationUtils to `isInBackground = true;`

and change `Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);` in class MyFirebaseMessagingService to `Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + true);`

that's all

Answer (score 1):

This is code for showing fcm notification on foreground:

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.Notification;
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.media.RingtoneManager;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
        import android.util.Log;

        import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
        import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
        import com.rehq.app.R;
        import com.rehq.app.activities.DrawerActivity;
        import com.rehq.app.activities.LoginActivity;
        import com.rehq.app.baseclass.BaseActivity;
        import com.rehq.app.dbhelper.DatabaseAccess;
        import com.rehq.app.utils.AppConfig;
        import com.rehq.app.utils.Constants;
        import com.rehq.app.utils.Utils;

        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;

public class Custom_FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMsgService";
    String activityName;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            try{
                //boolean from_bg = Boolean.parseBoolean(remoteMessage.getData().get("from_bg").toString());
                Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
                boolean show_fg =  Boolean.parseBoolean(data.get("show_fg"));

                activityName = Utils.getCurrentActivityName(this);

                if(activityName.contains(LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName())){
                    show_fg = true;
                }

                if(show_fg){
                    String event = data.get("Event-Name");
                    String title = data.get("title");
                    String body = data.get("body");
                    if(event!=null) {
                        if (event.equals("EVENT_NAME")) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
                                if(object!=null) {
                                    ((BaseActivity) BaseActivity.context).insertChatUser(object,true);
                                }
                                sendNotificationWithChatID(title, body, remoteMessage.getData().get("chat_id"));
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendNotificationWithChatID(String title,String messageBody,String chat_id) {
        try {
            Intent intent = null;
            if (activityName.contains(LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName())) {
                intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(this, DrawerActivity.class);
            }
            intent.putExtra("chat_id", chat_id);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            showNotification(title, messageBody, pendingIntent);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.i("uniq", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String title,String messageBody,PendingIntent pendingIntent){
        Uri customSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.rehq_brand);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pushlogo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(customSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of notification payloads.

> 1. notification payload
> 2. data payload

OS handles the first one when application is in back ground. To have control of data from Messaging service for both back ground and fore ground you need to use data payload.

Comment: I have send data payload from server side.. but still can't show notification in notification try when app is in foreground

Comment: you have to use remoteMessage.getData() instead remoteMessage.getNotification()

Comment: handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); here change method paramter to data

Comment: I have try, but notification still can't  appear in notification tray